# Which full backup will my diff backup be connected to?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am trying to understand exactly how backups work for SQL Server.

The hosting provider have a scheduled FULL backup every night. There are also a number of DIFF backups taken during the day.

We are now planning a transfer to another hosting provider and want to take a new full backup which we want to start at say 1 PM and then later transfer the DIFF backups. (The current hosting provider is responsible for the other backups, so we don't want to mess with those.)

Can two DIFF backups be "connected" to two different FULL backups? How do I make sure that the DIFF backup I take is related to the correct (my) FULL backup? (Ok, I realize the question is a bit fuzzy, please help me with proper concepts).

The source db is SQL Server 2012 and destination db is 2014 (both web editions).

Comment: `1.` If you're transferring a Full backup to the new provider why would you want or need the previous Differential backups? The new Full backup has everything. `2.` I've never even thought about a scenario like this but my inclination is to say that it isn't workable. The previous Differential backups are based off of a different Full backup so they wouldn't/shouldn't be valid for the new Full backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diff backup is connected to the last full backup taken. Simple like that.

I suggest you move the hosting provider taken backups instead of splitting the backup chain.